Will the JSN-SR04T Sensor Provide Accurate Readings in a Tank with Condensation? Alternative Water Level Measurement Methods?
I'm working on a water tank level monitoring project using an ESP8266 module and the JSN-SR04T ultrasonic sensor. The sensor will be placed inside the tank to measure the water level. However, I'm concerned that condensation inside the tank may affect the sensor's readings.
Will the JSN-SR04T give accurate measurements despite condensation?
If not, what are some reliable and cost-effective methods to measure water levels inside a tank that could work better in such conditions?
I'm looking for a cheap and reliable solution, as this project is budget-constrained.
Thank you in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See this https://forum.mysensors.org/topic/10627/jsn-sr04t-temperature-influencing-readings

See also this https://www.adafruit.com/product/3316
